# Neo4j. Dynamic query with multiple filters on nodes

Tags: filter, neo4j, cypher

I have nodes like this and I need apply filter to them

```
{
  "value": "ma",
  "object_field_id": 2293
}

{
  "value": 2,
  "object_field_id": 2294
}
```

---

```
MATCH (:UserData {user_id:19})-[:CARD]-(c:Card)-[:FIELD_GROUP]-()-[:FIELD]-(fi:Field) 
WHERE fi.object_field_id IN [23,24] 
  AND (fi.value=~('(?iu).*149.*') 
  AND fi.value=~('(?iu).*gb.*')) 
RETURN c
```

but it doesn't work with `AND`

Where is my mistake?

Comment: If this were my problem I would break it down into smaller parts  until I found the part that did not work, fix it then put the working parts back together until the entire query works.

Comment: Screen shots are not that helpful when it is possible to add the code here so that we may recreate a portion of the database and test it on our system.

Comment: Are you sure that you want find nodes that have a `value` property that contains `konst` and a `2` ? None of your example match this condition ...

Comment: Ok i'll build test data

Comment: @Guy Coder, I've created model of neo4j, here is complete cql: 

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ifkM2O9GPhcGW6OpaIZ7zj5KNL8yFYr9

Comment: Thanks for advice

Comment: Yes There is card label no Card but i can not edit post because of many code

Comment: Those parameters that you use in the query (2293, 2294, '.*konst.*') are missing in the test data.

Comment: You may use it like this: 

MATCH (:UserData {user_id:19})-[:CARD]-(c:Card)-[:FIELD_GROUP]-()-[:FIELD]-(fi:Field)  
WHERE fi.object_field_id IN [23,24] 
  AND (fi.value=~('(?iu).*149.*') 
  AND fi.value=~('(?iu).*gb.*')) 
return c

Comment: I have given a answer. Your query is working correctly as written with `AND`. If you have another question about this then please start a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Here Is Query data for to build relations and nodes:

```
    CREATE (a:UserData {user_id: 19})-[r:CARD]->(b:Card {name: "card"})
WITH count(*) as dummy

CREATE (a:FieldUserGroup {data_id: 1290})
WITH count(*) as dummy

CREATE (a:FieldUserGroup {data_id: 1280})
WITH count(*) as dummy

CREATE (a:FieldUserGroup {data_id: 1270})
WITH count(*) as dummy

MATCH (u:FieldUserGroup), (c:Card)  CREATE (c)-[:FIELD_GROUP]->(u)
WITH count(*) as dummy

create (f:Field {value: "jerry", object_field_id: 11})
WITH count(*) as dummy

create (f:Field {value: 2, object_field_id: 12})
WITH count(*) as dummy

create (f:Field {value: "tom", object_field_id: 13})
WITH count(*) as dummy

MATCH (f:FieldUserGroup {data_id: 1290}), (f2:Field) CREATE (f)-[:FIELD]->(f2)
WITH count(*) as dummy

CREATE (c:Field {value: "jack", object_field_id: 14})
WITH count(*) as dummy

CREATE (c:Field {value: 1234, object_field_id: 15})
WITH count(*) as dummy

CREATE (c:Field {value: "robin", object_field_id: 16})
WITH count(*) as dummy

MATCH (f:FieldUserGroup {data_id: 1280}), (c:Field {value: "jack", object_field_id: 14}) CREATE (f)-[:FIELD]->(c)
WITH count(*) as dummy

MATCH (f:FieldUserGroup {data_id: 1280}), (c:Field {value: 1234, object_field_id: 15}) CREATE (f)-[:FIELD]->(c)
WITH count(*) as dummy

MATCH (f:FieldUserGroup {data_id: 1280}), (c:Field {value: "robin", object_field_id: 16}) CREATE (f)-[:FIELD]->(c)
WITH count(*) as dummy

CREATE (c:Field {value: "zazaza", object_field_id: 17})
WITH count(*) as dummy

CREATE (c:Field {value: 6578970, object_field_id: 18})
WITH count(*) as dummy

CREATE (c:Field {value: "hamlet", object_field_id: 19})
WITH count(*) as dummy

MATCH (f:FieldUserGroup {data_id: 1270}), (c:Field {value: "zazaza", object_field_id: 17}) CREATE (f)-[:FIELD]->(c)
WITH count(*) as dummy

MATCH (f:FieldUserGroup {data_id: 1270}), (c:Field {value: 6578970, object_field_id: 18}) CREATE (f)-[:FIELD]->(c)
WITH count(*) as dummy

MATCH (f:FieldUserGroup {data_id: 1270}), (c:Field {value: "hamlet", object_field_id: 19}) CREATE (f)-[:FIELD]->(c)
WITH count(*) as dummy

CREATE (r:card {name: "card2"})
WITH count(*) as dummy

MATCH (r:card {name: "card2"}), (a:UserData {user_id: 19}) CREATE (a)-[:CARD]->(r)
WITH count(*) as dummy

CREATE (a:FieldUserGroup {data_id: 1260})
WITH count(*) as dummy

CREATE (a:FieldUserGroup {data_id: 1250})
WITH count(*) as dummy

CREATE (a:FieldUserGroup {data_id: 1240})
WITH count(*) as dummy

MATCH (f:FieldUserGroup {data_id: 1260}), (r:card {name: "card2"}) CREATE (r)-[:CARD]->(f)
WITH count(*) as dummy

MATCH (f:FieldUserGroup {data_id: 1250}), (r:card {name: "card2"}) CREATE (r)-[:CARD]->(f)
WITH count(*) as dummy

MATCH (f:FieldUserGroup {data_id: 1240}), (r:card {name: "card2"}) CREATE (r)-[:CARD]->(f)
WITH count(*) as dummy

CREATE (c:Field {value: "some value", object_field_id: 20})
WITH count(*) as dummy

CREATE (c:Field {value: "more value", object_field_id: 21})
WITH count(*) as dummy

CREATE (c:Field {value: "this is insane!", object_field_id: 22})
WITH count(*) as dummy

MATCH (f:FieldUserGroup {data_id: 1260}), (c:Field {object_field_id: 20}) CREATE (f)-[:FIELD]->(c)
WITH count(*) as dummy

MATCH (f:FieldUserGroup {data_id: 1260}), (c:Field {object_field_id: 21}) CREATE (f)-[:FIELD]->(c)
WITH count(*) as dummy

MATCH (f:FieldUserGroup {data_id: 1260}), (c:Field {object_field_id: 22}) CREATE (f)-[:FIELD]->(c)
WITH count(*) as dummy

CREATE (c:Field {value: 14948576, object_field_id: 23})
WITH count(*) as dummy

CREATE (c:Field {value: "GB", object_field_id: 24})
WITH count(*) as dummy

CREATE (c:Field {value: 1, object_field_id: 25})
WITH count(*) as dummy

MATCH (f:FieldUserGroup {data_id: 1250}), (c:Field {object_field_id: 23}) CREATE (f)-[:FIELD]->(c)
WITH count(*) as dummy

MATCH (f:FieldUserGroup {data_id: 1250}), (c:Field {object_field_id: 24}) CREATE (f)-[:FIELD]->(c)
WITH count(*) as dummy

MATCH (f:FieldUserGroup {data_id: 1250}), (c:Field {object_field_id: 25}) CREATE (f)-[:FIELD]->(c)
WITH count(*) as dummy

CREATE (c:Field {value: 2, object_field_id: 26})
WITH count(*) as dummy

CREATE (c:Field {value: "Marky", object_field_id: 27})
WITH count(*) as dummy

CREATE (c:Field {value: "Tom Born", object_field_id: 28})
WITH count(*) as dummy

MATCH (f:FieldUserGroup {data_id: 1240}), (c:Field {object_field_id: 26}) CREATE (f)-[:FIELD]->(c)
WITH count(*) as dummy

MATCH (f:FieldUserGroup {data_id: 1240}), (c:Field {object_field_id: 27}) CREATE (f)-[:FIELD]->(c)
WITH count(*) as dummy

MATCH (f:FieldUserGroup {data_id: 1240}), (c:Field {object_field_id: 28}) CREATE (f)-[:FIELD]->(c)
WITH count(*) as dummy
```

Answer (score 0):

UPD:

Here is query that works but only in one side by FieldUserGroup

```
MATCH (c:Card)-[:FIELD_GROUP]-()-[:FIELD]-(fi:Field) where (any(prop in keys(fi) where fi[prop] =~ '(?iu).*tom.*'))
return c
```